# Creating leaderboard in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

**Example**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vE5DSC5bQMuHGMk3IRtLqFpTlr6AsfFvk0hMYZLts7o/edit?usp=sharing

Let's say I have the following table

Table 1 is titled "Scoring"

|  | Tom | Mike | Carl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| G2 | 5 | 2 | 7 |
| Total | 9 | 3 | 12 |

I know I can use functions to determine what number is the largest (First place), second largest (Second Place) and third-largest (third place) number is...

> =LARGE(B4:D4, 1)

> =LARGE(B4:D4, 2)

> =LARGE(B4:D4, 3)

And that will return `12` `9` and `3` respectively. Is it possible to take those numbers, and get the name (from row 1) that corresponds to them? So my output would be `Carl` `Tom` and `Mike` in that order. If needed, two steps can be made (So step one is to get the number, and step two (In a different cell) is to find the name.

Here is what I want the final output to look like:

|  | Tom | Mike | Carl |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 1st | Carl |
| G2 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 2nd | Mike |
| Total | 9 | 3 | 12 | 3rd | Tom |

I guess I should mention that the names are stated externally, and are shown in the table above using `=Info!B[number]` and the totals are calculated from adding the G1 and G2 scores together.

Comment: Either you've made an error in your post or I am not understanding you clearly. You said that the order of values should be 12, 9, 3 ... but then you said the corresponding names should be "`Carl` `Mike` and `Tom` in that order." But as I see it, 12, 9, 3 corresponds to the names in order of `Carl` `Tom` `Mike` instead. Also, it is unclear *where* you would like the output. It would help move things along if you shared a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the posted data and clearly indicating where the results should go, as it will save the volunteers making their own spreadsheet first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that error and added a demo spreadsheet

Comment: You currently have your sheet link permission set to "Comment only" and "Cannot copy." So there is no way to work with the data, even by making a copy of the spreadsheet and working in that. Please change the permission to at least remove the copy restriction.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell G2, and copy down for as many places as you calculate.

`=index(B$1:D$1,1,match(F2,$B$5:$D$5,0))`

---

**Sample**
[image: sample1]

---

**Logic**

- In this sample, the values in Column E and Column F have been populated. Column E = text, Column F uses the `LARGE`  function.
- `match` - returns the column number in the range `$B$5:$D$5` that contains the value in column F
- `index` - returns the value (Name) in the range `B$1:D$1` that is in the column number returned by `match`

---

**ADDENDUM - Options#2**

In this example, only the text in Column E ("1st", "2nd", "3rd") is provided, the values in Column F and G are determined dynamically.

**Winners Scores**
Enter this formula in cell F2 and copy down:
`=large($A$5:$D$5,value(left(E2,1)))`

**Winner**
You could use the existing formula as described above, or use
`=index($B$1:$D$1,1,match(large($A$5:$D$5,value(left(E2,1))),$B$5:$D$5,0))`
for a completely dynamic formula.

[image: option2]

Comment: As a matter of interest: you have a header in row#2 for the round number. But each player has two scores - one for group 1, another for group 12. Is the "Round" header actually meaningful - what unique information does it identify?